# WPF - Создание нескольких кнопок в строке GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

GridView при заполненных полях закрыт от редактирования. При выгрузке данных в строке "Команда" должны генерироваться кнопки с функциональными возможностями правки строки. Пример - как на рисунке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До этого использовал `Hyperlink.RequestNavigate`, но размещение их друг под другом невозможно. XML разметку добавил ниже.

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Width="Auto" MaxWidth="50">
           <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" Command="{Binding Hyperlink_Open}">Открыть</Hyperlink>
       </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Покажите фрагмент разметки с шаблоном этой ячейки

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил в вопрос. Исправил в вопросе DataGrid на GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующую разметку:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink>Link 1</Hyperlink>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Hyperlink>Link 2</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой вариант — `StackPanel` с несколькими `TextBlock`

Comment: Как я не догадался за LineBreak... Спасибо!